# Express session keeps on logging me out

Tags: node.js, express-session

I decided to use express session instead of cookie session so that I can use the rolling option which is only available in express session that allows me to only sign out users based on inactivity.

Here is my setting:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: [keys.session.secret],
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 1200000               //20 minutes
    },
    rolling: true,
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
  }));
```

I have set the maxAge to 20 minutes but I keep on getting signed out every 3-4 minutes and I am not sure why

Comment: Since you are not using any Session Store, was the Server restarted by any chance?